# How to deal with DB2 for I journals statuses

Tags: db2, db2-400

To test a qshell script which automatically clean up journals older than 2 days in the DB2 for i I need to have some journals in statuses which are not Attached or Online (the script skips journals with such statuses). Could anybody help me and advise how to change/update journal statuses using System I navigator or SQL statements.

Currently I have items in the "Attached" status in the "Journal Receivers" part and when I change receiver for Journal, a new journal receiver is created in the Attached status and the previous one is moved to the Online status. I have not found any ways to move them to other statuses.
I also tried to get some information from the DISPLAY_JOURNAL using SQL statements however with any success.

```
select * from TABLE (QSYS2.DISPLAY_JOURNAL(
    'QSYS2',    -- put the JOURNAL_LIBRARY parameter value instead of 'JOURNAL_LIBRARY' (VARCHAR(10))
    'QSQJRN',   -- put the JOURNAL_NAME parameter value instead of 'JOURNAL_NAME' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the STARTING_RECEIVER_LIBRARY parameter value instead of 'STARTING_RECEIVER_LIBRARY' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the STARTING_RECEIVER_NAME parameter value instead of 'STARTING_RECEIVER_NAME' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the STARTING_TIMESTAMP parameter value instead of 'STARTING_TIMESTAMP' (TIMESTAMP)
    '', -- put the STARTING_SEQUENCE parameter value instead of 'STARTING_SEQUENCE' (DECIMAL(21,0))
    '', -- put the JOURNAL_CODES parameter value instead of 'JOURNAL_CODES' (VARCHAR(48))
    '', -- put the JOURNAL_ENTRY_TYPES parameter value instead of 'JOURNAL_ENTRY_TYPES' (VARCHAR(1200))
    '', -- put the OBJECT_LIBRARY parameter value instead of 'OBJECT_LIBRARY' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the OBJECT_NAME parameter value instead of 'OBJECT_NAME' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the OBJECT_OBJTYPE parameter value instead of 'OBJECT_OBJTYPE' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the OBJECT_MEMBER parameter value instead of 'OBJECT_MEMBER' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the USER parameter value instead of 'USER' (VARCHAR(10))
    '', -- put the JOB parameter value instead of 'JOB' (VARCHAR(26))
    ''  -- put the PROGRAM parameter value instead of 'PROGRAM' (VARCHAR(10))
    )) AS X

SQL Error [42704]: [SQL0204] DISPLAY_JOURNAL in QSYS2 type *N not found.
  [SQL0204] DISPLAY_JOURNAL in QSYS2 type *N not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISPLAY_JOURNAL is only available since version 7.2

however, don't you have enough options to control journal deletion ?
I let the IBM i manage them
[Methods to reduce the storage that journal receivers use](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaki/rzakireducesize.htm)

Comment: Checked my DB2i version - we use 7.1 :(

Answer (score 1):

Journal receiver status is not something you can change like a status field in a database table. It is the status of the object itself. You can delete receivers once they have been changed, and are no longer the attached receiver. However if you try to delete a receiver that has not been saved, it will give you a message to that effect. You can save a journal receiver even if it is attached, but the best thing, if you don't want the system to manage your receivers for you, is to save the receivers after you change them, then you are free to delete the receivers at any time.

So maybe you should save receivers with Online Status, then you can allow your script to delete them.

Comment: We use DB2I for testing, it's not a real environment so we do not need the journals at all and when we do a lot of transactions, the server storage becomes full and we have to do clean up manually, that's why we decided automate the clean up using Qshell.

Comment: In that case change the journals every night before backup, back them up, and delete the old receiver. You could even save them to a save file, and delete the save file. That would count as a save.